# Scraping page by Bs4 Python and remove multi spaces

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try scraping some part of page:
https://tuning-tec.com/mercedes_w164_ml_mklasa_0507_black_led_seq_lpmed0-5789i

To find elemets description u can enter to page like below:
https://tuning-tec.com/_template/_show_normal/_show_charlong.php?itemId=5789

Now i need to get part of english description

So i try get elemets by td in selected row like this:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://tuning-tec.com/mercedes_w164_ml_mklasa_0507_black_led_seq_lpmed0-5789i'
ajax_url = 'https://tuning-tec.com/_template/_show_normal/_show_charlong.php?itemId={}'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

item_id = re.findall(r"ajax_update_stat\('(\d+)'\)", soup.text)[0]
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(ajax_url.format(item_id)).content, 'html.parser')

def unwrapElements(soup, elementsToFind):
    elements = soup.find_all(elementsToFind)
    for element in elements:
        element.unwrap()

#Get content what i need (find tr and  get seconnd  td where is english description)
description=soup2.findAll('tr')[1].findAll('td')[1]
description.append(soup2.new_tag('br'))
description.append((soup2.findAll('tr')[2].findAll('td')[1]))
description.append(soup2.findAll('tr')[3].findAll('td')[1])
description.append(soup2.new_tag('br'))
description.append(soup2.findAll('tr')[4].findAll('td')[1])

#Remove tags what I dont wont
unwrapElements(description, "font")
unwrapElements(description, "span")
unwrapElements(description, "strong")
unwrapElements(description, "b")
unwrapElements(description, "td")

print(description)
```

Im so close to get good output i add some "BR" to break new line but i see multi spaces beetween

```
<td>Description<br/>Projector  
                                                     headlights with LED Parking 
                        light.<br/>With Dynamic Turn       
      Signal.<br/>100%       brand             new, come in       pair 
      (left &amp; right).<br/>Approval:                      
      E-marked E13 -        approved.    Details<br/>Parking    
                     light: LED<br/>Blinker: LED
<br/>Low 
                              beam: H9   included <br/>High beam:           
                 H1   included <br/>Regulation:        electrical (with build in    
                     electrical adjuster).</td>
```

And when i  put it to html i see "Â":

```
DescriptionProjector headlights with LED Parking light.
With Dynamic Turn Signal.
100% brand new, come in pair (left & right).
Approval: E-markedÂ E13Â - approved. DetailsParking light: LED
Blinker:Â LED
Low beam:Â H9Â Â Â includedÂ 
High beam: H1Â Â Â includedÂ 
Regulation: electrical (with build in electrical adjuster).
```

How I can fix it?

And second question.

Why in output  have td when i unwrap tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type` of `description` is `bs4.element.Tag`. You can get the text with `description.text` (this will get rid of the `<td>` tags).

The formatting is a bit weird, but I used a regex to remove extra spaces - all new lines flanked by spaces are replaced by a single space character. I then stripped extra spaces.

```
print(' '.join((re.sub(' *\n *',' ', description.text)).split()))

> DescriptionProjector headlights with LED Parking light.With Dynamic Turn Signal.100% brand new, come in pair (left & right).Approval: E-marked E13 - approved. DetailsParking light: LEDBlinker: LED Low beam: H9 included High beam: H1 included Regulation: electrical (with build in electrical adjuster).
```

Answer (score -1):

Thx its help me.

I just little change it

```
soup_string = str(description)

# print(soup_string)
print(' '.join((re.sub(' *\n *',' ', soup_string)).split()))
```

Couse i need "`<br>`" tags to break new lines  ".text" remove all tags

But your Answer are usefull for me.
Thanks so much